# Is it possible to start Google Photos slideshow automatically?

Tags: google-photos, automation, album

I know I can start a slideshow for my Google Photos album by going to **menu options** and selecting **Slideshow**.

Is it possible to share an album on Google+ so, when a user clicks on it, the slideshow starts automatically without going to a menu?